Does Protobuf proto2 format validate utf-8 format? Can validation be disabled in proto2?
In https://protobuf.dev/editions/features/#utf8_validation it seems that proto2 format should not result in UTF-8 validation.
When I run Perf on a program doing protobuf encoding I can however see that utf-8 validation seems to be done.
Which is not seen when string is changed to bytes.
So is any other settings needed for proto2 format to disable utf-8 validation?
syntax="proto2";
message Orange {
  optional string color = 1;
}

With Perf I see:
**google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::VerifyUTF8String**
**google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::VerifyUTF8StringNamedField**
Orange::_InternalSerialize
google::protobuf::SerializeToArrayImpl

I did not expect VerifyUTF8String* to show up for this case.

Please update your question so that it's a minimal reproducible example of the issue. You wrote "run Perf on a program doing protobuf encoding", please include the code, what you did, what you saw, and what you expected.
